# Update query with 2 tables

Tags: sql, oracle

I have 2 tables, table1 and table2.

table1 has 2 columns: status and id

and table2 has 2 columns: id and name

I have a function that receives a name and I want to update table1.status to be 0 where table1.id = table2.id and table2.name = the name I receive.

I tried looking around but every query I have tried has failed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `update`:

```
update table1 t1
     set status = 0
     where exists (select 1 
                   from table2 t2
                   where t2.id = t1.id and t2.name = :name
                  );
```

Comment: @MayaSaias If the answer resolved your problem, you can accept it. This way you can reward the ppl for answering. It also shows future ppl who have the same problem which solution did work.

Comment: @Gordon, I upvote your answer, because it solves the problem and because the user apparently forgot to accept it. I am suffering this a lot too and for that I bound myself to upvote the answers from people when they are good  obviously, but also when they solve the question itself and the people who asked forgot or did  not care.